# Trying to use the GitHub GUI and I come across "GitHub for Mac version is too old"

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I tried to install GitHub GUI because I'm new to github.
However, I installed the newest version of the github GUI I could find (straight from the github site itself)

But when I try to log in using the GUI, it claims
"GitHub for Mac version is too old"

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select 'Skip Setup' add this step, add you local repository, then enter your username and password/token when you select 'Sync'.

I'm sorry to say I haven't found a way to change the global GitHub.app setting, and hope this will be resolved in a future release.